# How do i create a bootable ISO usb?

Tags: boot, usb, ubuntu-netbook

I bought an HP Netbook it doesnt have a CD ROM Drive,

I then bought an elite HP laptop off a well know shopping site, it was delivered and on powerup it goes to bitlocker screen,  I am not interested in the contents of the laptop but need to get it working

I can download the ISO on my netbook, but dont know how to create a bootable USB from download - I need to keep the netbook as microsoft (unfortunately) so cant use the help on ubuntu ...

Please help?  Note I am not technically minded and a friend directed me to the site from the US.
Sail

Comment: Also, google this: linux iso pen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tool, I always use to create bootable Ubuntu ISO on USB [LILI USB Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/). You can use this tool to create bootable ISO. Although, tool is simple, still if you find some difficulty in using this tool, Here's the [User Guide](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/help/guide)

Comment: IT WORKED - Thank you Sooooooo much (excuse my spelling - just so happy)!  Really simple and easy to follow.  S

Answer (score 2):

There is a program called `Rufus` that will burn an ISO to a USB stick using Windows. Here's the home page: https://rufus.akeo.ie/

Comment: Thank you, i didnt feel technically apt, but was what my friend eventually came back with too! Really appreciate your reply! S

Comment: If you think it's what answer your question best, mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). It is available for Windows, Linux and Mac.

Check Disk image and choose the iso file from your device. Then pick usb drive and click ok.

Answer (score 1):

There is a guide on ubuntu website! http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Comment: Link-only answers aren't encouraged. The link may be removed and the content will be lost. You can post the important parts here.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... :-( Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! ;-) You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...